# Creating a loop to open links in sequence

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

This site:
https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/european-championships/c25/

```
EUROPE

European Championship
                     2020
                         Group Stage
                         Final Stages
EC Qualification
WC Qualification Europe
UEFA Nations League
Baltic Cup
```

It has two links on the left side menu expanse in `Group Stage` and `Final Stages`:

```
https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/r38188/
https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/european-championships/2020/s13030/final-stages/
```

I'm managing to collect the links, but when I try to open the pages one after the other, it only stops at the first link and doesn't open the second one, what should I change?

```
url = "https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/european-championships/c25/"

driver.get(url)
links_level_2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'level-2')]/li/a")
for link_level_2 in links_level_2:
    level_2 = link_level_2.get_attribute("href")
    driver.get(level_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with `beautifulsoup`.

Since you haven't clearly mentioned what those `links` are, I assume that you are trying to extract the `links` under `ul` looking at our code.

Here is the code using `beautifulsoup`. *It gets you the links under `<ul>` from both the links mentioned.*

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

urls = ['https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/r38188/', 'https://int.soccerway.com/international/europe/european-championships/2020/s13030/final-stages/']
headers = {"User-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36"}

#Code to get the ULs
for url in urls:
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
    ls = soup.find('ul', class_='level-2').findAll('li')
    for i in ls:
        print(i.find('a')['href'])
    print('\n')
```

```
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/r38188/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/group-a/g10136/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/group-b/g10137/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/group-c/g10138/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/group-d/g10139/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/group-e/g10140/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/group-f/g10141/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/s13030/final-stages/


/international/europe/european-championships/2020/group-stage/r38188/
/international/europe/european-championships/2020/s13030/final-stages/
```